# Difference Between Marker based and Markerless Augmented Reality

Tags: augmented-reality

I am totally new to AR and I searched on the internet about marker based and markerless AR but I am confused with marker based and markerless AR..
Lets assume an AR app triggers AR action when it scans specific images..So is this marker based AR or markerless AR..
Isn't the image a marker?
Also to position the AR content does marker based AR use devices' accelerometer and compass as in markerless AR?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In a **marker-based AR** application **the images** (or the corresponding image descriptors) to be recognized **are provided beforehand**. In this case you know *exactly* what the application will search for while acquiring camera data (camera frames).  Most of the nowadays AR apps dealing with image recognition are marker-based. Why? Because it's much more simple to detect things that are hard-coded in your app.

On the other hand, a **marker-less AR** application **recognizes *things* that were not directly provided to the application beforehand**. This scenario is much more difficult to implement because the recognition algorithm running in your AR application has to **identify patterns, colors or some other features** that may exist in camera frames. For example if  your algorithm is able to identify dogs, it means that the AR application will be able to trigger AR actions whenever a dog is detected in a camera frame, without you having to provide images with all the dogs in the world (this is exaggerated of course - training a database for example) when developing the application.

Long story short: in a marker-based AR application where image recognition is involved, the marker can be an image, or the corresponding descriptors (features + key points). Usually an AR marker is a black&white (square) image,a QR code for example. These markers are easily recognized and tracked => not a lot of processing power on the end-user device is needed to perform the recognition (and optionally tracking).

There is no need of an accelerometer or a compass in a marker-based app. The recognition library may be able to compute the [pose matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pose_%28computer_vision%29) (rotation & translation) of the detected image relative to the camera of your device. If you know that, you know how far the recognized image is and how it is rotated relative to your device's camera. And from now on, AR begins... :)

Answer (score 7):

Well. Since I got downvoted without explanation. Here is a little more detail on markerless tracking:

Actual there are several possibilities for augmented reality without "visual" markers but none of them called markerless tracking.

Showing of the virtual information can be triggered by GPS, Speech or simply turning on your phone.

Also, people tend to confuse NFT(Natural feature tracking) with markerless tracking. With NFT you can take a real life picture as a marker. But it is still a "marker".

This site has a nice overview and some examples for each marker:
[Marker-Types](http://anymotion.com/en/wissensgrundlagen/augmented-reality-marker)
It's mostly in german but so beware.

What you call markerless tracking today is a technique best observed with the Hololens(and its own programming language) or the AR-Framework [Kudan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSejIqGy_J8). Markerless Tracking doesn't find anything on his own. Instead, you can place an object at runtime somewhere in your field of view. 
Markerless tracking is then used to keep this object in place. It's most likely uses a combination of sensor input and solving the SLAM( simultaneous localization and mapping) problem at runtime.

EDIT: A Little update. It seems the hololens creates its own inner geometric representation of the room. 3D-Objects are then put into that virtual room. After that, the room is kept in sync with the real world. The exact technique behind that seems to be unknown but some speculate that it is based on the Xbox Kinect technology.

Answer (score 4):

Let's make it simple:

1. **Marker-based** augmented reality is when the tracked object is black-white square marker. A great example that is really easy to follow shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbEDkDGB-9w): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbEDkDGB-9w (you can try out by yourself)
2. **Markerless** augmented reality is when the tracked object can be anything else: picture, human body, head, eyes, hand or fingers etc. and on top of that you add virtual objects.

To sum it up, position and orientation information is the essential thing for Augmented Reality that can be provided by various sensors and methods for them. If you have that information accurate - you can create some really good AR applications.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there may be some confusion between Marker tracking and Natural Feature Tracking (NFT). A lot of AR SDK's tote their tracking as Markerless (NFT). This is still marker tracking, in that a pre-defined image or set of features is used. It's just not necessarily a black and white AR Toolkit type of marker. Vuforia, for example, uses NFT, which still requires a marker in the literal sense. Also, in the most literal sense, hand/face/body tracking is also marker tracking in that the marker is a shape. Markerless, inherent to the name, requires no pre-knowledge of the world or any shape or object be present to track.

You can read more about how Markerless tracking is achieved [here](http://www.marxentlabs.com/markerless-augmented-reality-marxent-part-1/), and see multiple examples of both marker-based and Markerless tracking [here](http://www.marxentlabs.com/ar-solution/visualcommerce-mobile/).

Answer (score 1):

Marker based AR uses a Camera and a visual marker to determine the center, orientation and range of its spherical coordinate system. ARToolkit is the first full featured toolkit for marker based tracking.

Markerless Tracking is one of best methods for tracking currently.  It performs active tracking and recognition of real environment on any type of support without using special placed markers. Allows more complex application of Augmented Reality concept.